# Can I install kernel package built for ubuntu xenial on my ubuntu trusty machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

As we all know, ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) is approaching its EOL (april 2019). The security updates will no longer be provided.

Can I use kernel package built for other ubuntu version on my **trusty** machine? I installed the following packages from ubuntu **xenial** repo:

```
linux-base_4.5ubuntu1~16.04.1_all.deb
linux-headers-4.15.0-45_4.15.0-45.48~16.04.1_all.deb
linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic_4.15.0-45.48~16.04.1_amd64.deb
linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic_4.15.0-45.48~16.04.1_amd64.deb
linux-modules-4.15.0-45-generic_4.15.0-45.48~16.04.1_amd64.deb
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-45-generic_4.15.0-45.48~16.04.1_amd64.deb
```

then rebooted the machine. And it looks like everything works.

Are there any pitfalls to this solution? (note that I do understand that upgrading the kernel won't make **trusty** secure after its EOL. I'm doing this because I need to run trusty on new hardware)

Comment: Are there no backports available for trusty? And pitfalls like perhaps none of your software has been tested on that kernel? I'm not actually sure how the kernels are tested... why not just update to a new release like 16.04, 18.04, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly enough, migration to 4.15 was a success.

One minor problem we encountered was CIFS. Turned out CIFS mounts prefer SMB protocol version 3 in kernel 4.15 (the solution was to specify version 1.0 in /etc/fstab for our CIFS mounts)